# Only show friends posts on Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, instagram

new programmer trying to learn Swift and I'm trying to set my app up to only show the current users post on a parse photosharing database. The first method here in theory should add the current user to the "followingWho" array.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery?.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


        if error == nil {
            //no error
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    let followingWho = object["followingWho"] as! NSArray!
                    self.loadData(followingWho)
                }
            }

        } else {
            //error 
            NSLog("Error")
        }
    })


    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

}

then my second method here should display the posts and filter out all but the current users

```
func loadData(followingWho: NSArray) {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.whereKey("addedBy", containedIn: followingWho as! [PFObject])
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?)  -> Void in


        if (error == nil) {
            //No error

            //let posts = posts as! [PFObject]

            if let posts = posts {
                for post in posts {
                    self.images.append(post["Image"] as! PFFile)
                    self.imageCaptions.append(post["Caption"] as! String)
                    self.imageDates.append(post["date"] as! String)
                    self.imageUsers.append(post["addedby"] as! String)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else {
            //error
            NSLog("Error")
        }

    }

}
```

But nothing seems to be working. The code compiles and runs but it seems to only pull up a blank screen loading none of the posts.

Comment: FYI - Parse.com is shutting down in a few months. You should find another service.

Comment: I understand that I'm just learning on it as I knew how to set it up and it's a simple database service

Answer (score 0):

This *could* be the problem, although if it is not *the* problem, it is certainly *a* problem: you are trying to update the UI from a background thread. `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` calls its completion block in the background, and updating UI from the background is a big no-no. Instead, call your UI updates on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    //Do your UI updates here
})
```